# Does postgresql support updatable inline view

Tags: postgresql

I supposed this SQL work in Oracle

`update
  (select TABLE1.COL1 as T1C1, TABLE1.COL2 as T1C2, TABLE2.COL1 as T2C1
     from TABLE1 join TABLE2 on TABLE2.COL2 = TABLE1.COL2
  )
  set T1C1 = T2C1;`

But when try this kind of inline sql in postgresql it got syntax error. How to convert the above sql to postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
UPDATE table1
SET col1 = table2.col1
FROM table2
WHERE table1.col2 = table2.col2;
```

In postgres you can add `FROM any_table` directly to `UPDATE` and join the tables